# Where can I find the file explorer in Android studio 1.0.1?

Tags: android, file, explorer, ddms

I found a lot of similar questions to mine and everyone tells me it's under Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. I did this and there I have to select the file explorer tab, the problem is there is no such tab. The only thing I see is a list with my devices and a logcat. Anyone knows where I can find the file explorer in Android studio because I don't see it in my DDMS.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: file explorer for your device, emulator, project...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for the file explorer for your device/emulator:
Tool > Android > Android Device Monitor. Then you see the list of devices on the left. Click the device you want to explore, and then you can select the File Explorer Tab.
If you can't find it, you have probably closed it. You can reopen it by pressing the small android logo on the right side of the window, or Window > Reset perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `green Android icon`. It will open `Android Device Monitor`.

[image: green Android icon]

Alternatively, you can open `Android Device Monitor`by following way:

[image: Tools Menu]

Now click on `file explorer`.

[image: file explorer]

If you closed `file explorer` by mistake, you can open it by clicking

```
Window -> Reset Perspective
```

[image: Reset Perspective]

Comment: That's the problem, when I open the Android Device Monitor it doesn't open a new screen. It opens a new pinned window inside my Android studio with no tab options at all, it looks different from everything people show in tutorials. I only have a tab for my devices and a logcat and another tab for ADB logs but nothing else. I didn't delete the other tabs because it's the first time I opened this.